# What would be the fastest way, to calculate a square root rounded to an integer?

Tags: performance, optimization, mathematical-optimization, generic-programming

What would be the fastest way, to calculate a square root rounded to an integer in terms of performance?

Comment: [Methods of computing square roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots)

Comment: I already looked that up. But i cant seem to find the right one

Comment: You didn't say you looked Wikipedia up in your question.  Pick one square root formula like the Babylonian method, implement it, and see how long it takes.

Comment: Surely the answer depends on the nature of the numbers that you are taking the square root of. Fixed size ints? Doubles? Big ints? Also, the answer is unlikely to be language-agnostic. In C you could experiment with low-level bit shifting. In Python it is probably a bad idea to do anything other than use the built-in function.

Comment: @John Coleman absolutely, and in addition to language and size of integer, it also depends on the platform, since integer square roots are usually reserved for very small-scale embedded systems.  Many small-scale embedded controllers do not even have hardware integer multiplication, and no hardware floating point capability at all.  For everything else, even modern phones generally have vector floating point units now.  A lot more info on the platform, language, and resource availability will be required to answer this, along with some idea of how it will be used.